# How will the page scroll to the next section if the arrow is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want that when I click on the arrow, the website will scroll down to the next section, called rest in my code. So it will move `100vh`. I don't know how I must do this, I think there must be some JS in it. Does anyone know how I can get what I want? See image below, so it will be clear. Thanks in advance!

**HTML:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=Ddevice-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Korps Commandotroepen</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style5.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="bg">
            <button class="button">
                <div class="button__arrow button__arrow--down"></div>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="rest">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
.bg{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: black;
}
.button {
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 8px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    position: fixed; 
    bottom:8%;
}
.button__arrow {
    background-color: transparent;
    height: 12px;
    width: 12px;
}
.button__arrow--down {
    border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border-right: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    transform: translateY(-25%) rotate(45deg);
}
.rest{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: aliceblue;
}
```

**Image:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple approach using `scroll-behavior: smooth;` and `a` tag instead of `button`.

```js
window.onscroll = function () {
    var height = $(window).height();
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var obj = $('#scroll');
    var pos = obj.position();
    if (height + scrollTop < pos.top) {
       $('.button').fadeIn();
    }
    else {
       $('.button').fadeOut(); 
    }
}
```

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
}

.button {
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 8%;
  background: #ccc;
}

.button__arrow {
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
}

.button__arrow--down {
  border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-right: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transform: translateY(-25%) rotate(45deg);
}

.rest {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=Ddevice-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Korps Commandotroepen</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style5.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="bg">
    <a href="#scroll" class="button">
      <div class="button__arrow button__arrow--down"></div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="scroll" class="rest"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to hide the button when I clicked on it?

Comment: Yes, just use this `onclick="window.location.href='#scroll';this.style.display = 'none'"`

Comment: Do you now how the button can be showed if I scroll up again?

Comment: Yeah, please check the updated code snippet.

Comment: It doesn't work. When I click on it will disappear and when I scroll backup it doesn't show up. that is because when I click on it, the url will change to `../index8.html#scroll`.

Comment: I made it work. I added after `var pos`  `if (height = 0) {}` and now it works.

Comment: Actually it is a lot easier. I have deleted your JS and I've discoverd a bug in my CSS. I deleted the `position: fixed` of the `button`.

Answer (score 1):

```
   <html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=Ddevice-width, initial- 
scale=1.0">
<title>Korps Commandotroepen</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style5.css">
 </head>
 <body>
<div class="bg">
    <button class="button">
        <div class="button__arrow button__arrow--down" id="button__arrow         
button__arrow--down" onClick="topFunction()"></div>
    </button>
</div>
    <div class="rest">

    </div>
 <script>

var mybutton = document.getElementById("button__arrow button__arrow-- 
down");

var close = document.getElementsByClassName("button")[0];

function topFunction() {
document.body.scrollTop = 1000;
document.documentElement.scrollTop = 1000;
}
var close = document.getElementsByClassName("button")[0];
close.onclick = function() {
  close .style.display = "none";
}
</script>
<style>
.bg{
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
background-color: black;
}
.button {
border-radius: 20px;
padding: 8px;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
-ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
transform: translateX(-50%);
position: fixed; 
bottom:8%;
}
.button__arrow {
background-color: transparent;
height: 12px;
width: 12px;
}
.button__arrow--down {
border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
border-right: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
transform: translateY(-25%) rotate(45deg);
}
.rest{
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
background-color: aliceblue;
}
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: .second being the div class you want to scroll to

Comment: Can you put the code together? I think I make a mistake, because when I put this code in `<script>` it doesn't work.

Comment: $("button").click(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".rest").offset().top},
    'slow');
    });

Comment: This is JavaScript right? It still doesn't work.

Comment: make sure everything is correctly back spaced, so the class name is on the same line without spaces document.getElementById("button__arrow button__arrow--down");

Comment: How can I hide the button after I clicked on it?

Comment: var close = document.getElementsByClassName("button")[0];
close.onclick = function() {
  close .style.display = "none";
}

Comment: make sure to add id="button__arrow         
button__arrow--down" to class="button__arrow button__arrow--down" div

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it by simply putting arrow in  tag and in href give the id of rest.

```css
  
CSS:

.bg{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: black;
}
.button {
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 8px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    position: fixed; 
    bottom:8%;
}
.button__arrow {
    background-color: transparent;
    height: 12px;
    width: 12px;
}
.button__arrow--down {
    border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border-right: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    transform: translateY(-25%) rotate(45deg);
}
.rest{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: aliceblue;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=Ddevice-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Korps Commandotroepen</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style5.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="bg">
    <button class="button">
                <a href="#rest"><div class="button__arrow button__arrow--down"></div></a>
            </button>
  </div>
  <div class="rest" id="rest">

  </div>
</body>

</html>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Comment: Yeah, thank you! This works. I didn't know this was possible with CSS and HTMl

Comment: Do you know how I can hide the button when I clicked on it?

Comment: Yes, by a bit of JS you can easily that – use event listener on that button and when clicked set display to none

Answer (score 1):

see this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollBy

```
window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight);
```